Zathura ignoring interactive table of contents
When hovering a mouse cursor over a TOC entry it shows the proper (index finger) icon, but no action follows the clicking. What should I check?

First error: Using a mouse cursor. You're using Zathura, so use hint mode :P

Have you tried to double-click on the TOC entry in Zathura, it works for me.
Else, make sure you have loaded the hyperref package.

Thank you very much!

@AlexeyOrlov You're welcome!
